# getElementById doesn't find element after setting visibility to hidden

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm working on an asp.net page, and I have a master page that uses a content page (my web control).  In my web control, I have 4 elements.  When I change the picklisttype drop down

PickListType - dropdown
   UserPickList -not important
   Organization - label
   Body - label
   Address -drop down

When I change the picklisttype dropdwon, I want to hide Body and Address, and vice versa.

When I change it hte first time, it works, but the second time, it says that it cannot find the ids of Body and Address (I set their visibility to hidden) the 2nd time.  When looking through the source, it seems that these elements have 1) changed their Ids during the postback and .ClientId can't find them or 2) they just disappear.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  Any ideas?

```
function DropDownChange() {

            var picklist = document.getElementById("PickListTypeList");
            var usercontainer = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder_PageContentPlaceHolder_paneDetails_ApplicerPickListContainer");
            var orgcontainer = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder__C_OrganizationPickListContainer");
            var addresslabel = document.getElementById("LegalBodyAddressLabel");
            var addressbox = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder_PageContentPlaceHolder_paneDetails_ApplicantsRadDock_C_ApplicantsControl_AddEditApplicantDock_C_AddApplicantDock_C_LegalBodyAddressComboBox");


            if(picklist.value.toLowerCase() === "sometext"){
                usercontainer.style.display = "none";
                orgcontainer.style.display = "inline";
                addresslabel.visibility = "visible";
                addressbox.style.display = "inline";
            }
            else{
                usercontainer.style.display = "inline";
                orgcontainer.style.display = "none";
                addresslabel.visibility = "hidden";
                addressbox.style.visiblity = "none";

            }


            }
```

This is the source: i use .ClientId to dynamically find the ids, but then I changed it to static (same id's every single time) and I still cannot seem to get address and label.  I am finding these elements from the parent (master) page by going into the control (controlname.nameofelementID.ClientID).

Comment: Since .NET wants to hog all of the IDs, it's often easier to use CSS class names instead. You can give them meaningful names that are short.

Comment: What are these three: `addresslabel.visibility = "visible"; addresslabel.visibility = "hidden";            addressbox.style.visiblity = "none";`?

Comment: I rollbacked your edit. Use the delete button or flag your post if you want it removed.

Answer (score 1):

2 ideas/options

- Add a class to the controls you want to access, and then use `document.getElementsByClassName` to retrieve them. .NET will not change classes on html tags after a postback.

OR

- Wrap them in a div/span that has an id, and then `document.getElementById` that wrapping tag and then access its `firstChild`. I would recommend not doing `runat="server"` for this wrapper

Answer (score 1):

You've 2 ways to make it work:

1. Use class names (.net framework does not fiddle with this)
2. Generate the javascript ids (using ClientId) at runtime. Since there's a postback, this is the right thing to do. Something like: `document.getElementById("<%=LegalBodyAddressLabel.ClientId%>");`